# Android: How to add checkbox preferences dynamically and display them in preference screen (SharedPreferences)

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to implement functionality where user will be able to select which group of items to be displayed using checkbox shared preferences. To be precise I will read checked items from the preferences and display.

Here is my preferences class

```
 public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             //One way to add default preferences
    //addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

             //For now I prefer this
    setPreferenceScreen(defaultPref());

}

    // The first time application is launched this should be read
private PreferenceScreen defaultPref() {
    PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);

    CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
    checkboxPref.setKey("1");
    checkboxPref.setTitle("SomeRandomStuff");
    root.addPreference(checkboxPref);

    return root;
 }
     public showAllPreferences () {
          // TO SHOW ALL THE PREFERENCES BUT NOT SURE HOW TO DISPLAY THEM
     }
}
```

Now I cannot understand how do I add more preferences dynamically and display them in preference screen.

Here is the main activity class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    exView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);

    // STUFF TO ADD IN PREFERENCES 
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    //BUTTON TO ADD PREFERENCES.(SEARCH TERM IS IDENTIFIED AND ADDED TO PREF)
    addButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    // BUTTON TO DISPLAY PREFERENCES
    prefButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPref);

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            PrefObject obj = new PrefObject();
            String key = Integer.toString(i);
            String title = editText.getText().toString();
            //prefArray.add(obj);
            editor.putString(key, title);
            editor.commit();
                            i++

        }
    });
    prefButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        // This method should show the preferences activity with new data
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Preferences.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                            // I know how to call the intent but I am not sure if
                            // how to read the saved contents and display it
                            Preferences pref = new Preferences();
                            pref.showAllPreferences();  





        }
    });
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287067/adding-dynamic-checkbox-preferences-in-android-and-display-them-in-preference-s