# Adding dynamic checkbox preferences in Android, and display them in preference screen?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to implement functionality where user will be able to select which group of items to be displayed using checkbox shared preferences. To be precise I will read checked items from the preferences and display.

Here is my preferences class

```
 public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             //One way to add default preferences
    //addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

             //For now I prefer this
    setPreferenceScreen(defaultPref());

}

    // The first time application is launched this should be read
private PreferenceScreen defaultPref() {
    PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);

    CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
    checkboxPref.setKey("1");
    checkboxPref.setTitle("SomeRandomStuff");
    root.addPreference(checkboxPref);

    return root;
 }
     public showAllPreferences () {
          // TO SHOW ALL THE PREFERENCES BUT NOT SURE HOW TO DISPLAY THEM
     }
}
```

Now I cannot understand how do I add more preferences dynamically and display them in preference screen.

Here is the main activity class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    exView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);

    // STUFF TO ADD IN PREFERENCES 
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    //BUTTON TO ADD PREFERENCES.(SEARCH TERM IS IDENTIFIED AND ADDED TO PREF)
    addButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    // BUTTON TO DISPLAY PREFERENCES
    prefButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPref);

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            PrefObject obj = new PrefObject();
            String key = Integer.toString(i);
            String title = editText.getText().toString();
            //prefArray.add(obj);
            editor.putString(key, title);
            editor.commit();
                            i++

        }
    });
    prefButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        // This method should show the preferences activity with new data
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Preferences.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                            // I know how to call the intent but I am not sure if
                            // how to read the saved contents and display it
                            Preferences pref = new Preferences();
                            pref.showAllPreferences();  





        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no "visibility" option for preferences, which kinda makes sense when you think it's all just a ListView.

See [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2240352/489607)]. For what I see, you could do something like this:

```
PreferenceScreen screen = this.getPreferenceScreen();
// Use "1" since you're using "1" to create it.
CheckBoxPreference ckbox = (CheckBoxPreference) this.findPreference("1");
screen.removePreference(ckbox);
```

To recreate, you could do this [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4704360/489607)]:

```
screen.addPreference(ckbox);
```

Additionally, remember to create your preference using the `setOrder(int order)` so that when you recreate, it will be recreated in the proper position.

As you can see, it could be worth to keep a global reference to the preference to make it easier and faster.

Of course, I don't need to tell that you should integrate that logic into your CheckboxPreference listener. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/531927/489607) by nobody else than Reto Meier himself to see a good way of doing it (it's a checkbox, too). There he registers a listener to the whole screen and checks which preference triggered the listener, but you can do it simpler (but more verbose later on) by just setting its `setOnPreferenceChangeListener`.

*edit: I see that you're also using a button to add the preference. You can also implement the same logic above into the button itself. It all depends if you want to do this using a checkbox or a button.

Finally, it could be worth to just set the enabled state, unless you are doing something like "see advanced preferences" or something worth to keep novice users away from doing dangerous stuff to your app. But generally the enable states work better for user experience, IMHO.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: hey thanks for your response I still have a question. Is it possible to create preferences on the fly? Consider I do not provide any default preference when the application is first launched but now is it possible to add preferences consider e.g. name of the city to be displayed or any news feed that user searches and adds into his preferences list.

Comment: Of course it is possible. You just need to use `PreferenceManager`. There are many methods that you can use, just search for that class here and on Google. If your app is too big, I suggest you encapsulate all that into a class (e.g., 'MySettings.java'). If you want to create defaults, you create a preference with a boolean key called "first_use" and catch that on your first activity, as soon as you enter the app. Change to false after the first time. While, you create the defaults, or you can just leave the defaults in code. Again, search Google for `PreferenceManager` and you'll see how.

Comment: Re preference visibility, `android.support.v7.preference.Preference` does have `isVisible()` and `setVisible()`. However, this seems to be implemented by adding the preference to its group or removing it: calling `setVisible()` twice with a `true` argument causes the preference to show twice; calling it twice with a `false` argument throws an exception.